# Intercept checklogin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, md5

I need to intercept the login page.
I try to be brief. I will change the login system, and at the user registration I will save the email encrypted in md5.

So when the user logs in with his email, the system should look for the email encrypted in md5 and not in clear text.

How can I intercept the login?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hook

```
function customcode($username, $password ) {
  if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    // your code
  }
}
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'customcode', 30, 2);
```